# SQLite 3 database is not updated

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code running on Windows 8 x64:

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table films(title text, year text, director text)")
print("table created")

cursor.execute('insert into films values("Annie Hall","1977","Woody Allen")')
cursor.execute('insert into films values("The Godfather","1972","Francis Ford Coppola")')

conn.close()
```

Checking the SQLite file that is created (test.db) (using [sqlite command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071700.zip) to test if there are entries in the table created via the code) shows nothing.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to call `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`.

If you want *autocommit* mode you've to put `isolation_level=None` as argument for `db.connect()` call.

Comment: That's only if he's operating in transaction mode and support for database transactions is optional, according to the [PEP that defines DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

Comment: If I remember correctly `isolation_level` isn't in *autocommit* mode by default. Anyway I've just followed the manual example: http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html :)

Answer (score 0):

The [spec](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects) says that the cursor can be read only, or that your database may be in transaction mode. I am also unclear as to why you are using [execute](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) without specifying your parameters in a prepared statement, as in `cursor.execute('insert into films values(?,?,?)', 'Annie Hall', '1977', 'Woody Allen')`. Try these ideas, I don't see any error off the top of my head in your code, but am just suggesting best practices.